# Load static file on Google Compute Engine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I started a virtual machine on Google Compute Engine with a docker image containing nginx with an angular app. I should inject an external configuration file, but I cant't load by using Cloud storage bucket. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Instance Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) to store configuration for your machine.

Then in [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) you can use curl to retrieve that metadata, place it in proper place and start container.

Example command to retrieve metadata:

`curl -s -f 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/your-attribute' -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found the startup-script metadata to provide a script that create a static file under /assets angular folder, but I think docker is not running at vm startup

Comment: Just start that docker with -d flag in your startup script :) and I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer or give some "up" :)